# ORA-12529 for Connecting to Oracle ATP Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created an ATP database and I want to connect to it remotely from SQL Developer. When I tried to connect using the wallet files, I got this error:

Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12529, TNS:connect request rejected based on current filtering rules (CONNECTION_ID=DaiNx3GxQoKa7gYAEdsmwQ==)

This is how my ATP looks like

[image]

And this is the error I got:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that you aren't using the right wallet, since it doesn't appear that you have any network access controls in place.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I select the wallet-zip-file I am able to connect from SQL Developer.
This is the script I use to download and unpack in order to utilize sqlplus.

```
cat download-wallet-autonomous-database.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# set environment (password)
. env.sh

DBNAME=demodb
DB_WALLET_FILE=demodb_wallet.zip

# create directory where to download the wallet
mkdir -p connection/${DBNAME} || true
cd connection/${DBNAME}

# now, generate and retreive the wallet
oci db autonomous-database generate-wallet \
  --generate-type all \
  --autonomous-database-id $DBID \
  --file ${DB_WALLET_FILE} \
  --password "${ADMIN_PASSWORD}"

# unzip wallet file. All connection details are unpacked (sqlnet,tnsnames.ora,certificates)
unzip ${DB_WALLET_FILE}

# replace "?/network/admin" by current directory
sed -i '' 's:?/network/admin:'`pwd`':' sqlnet.ora

export TNS_ADMIN=$(pwd)

cat > env.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
export ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
export TNS_ADMIN=\$(pwd)
export TWO_TASK=${DBNAME}_high
EOF

# handy for later sqlplus connection
cat > connect.sh <<EOF
. env.sh
rlwrap sqlplus admin/\${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
EOF
```

I need the DBID (redacted)

```
./list-autonomous-databases.sh
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DBName | DBWorkoad | Display | Status    | id                                                                                                       |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEMODB | OLTP      | DEMODB  | AVAILABLE | ocid1.autonomousdatabase.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, download wallet

```
./download-wallet-autonomous-database.sh ocid1.autonomousdatabase.oc1.eu-frankfurt-1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Both, sqlplus and SQL Developer works as expected.

```
./connect.sh

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Aug 7 11:25:56 2022
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Aug 07 2022 11:14:14 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

admin@MNYYI81SOQCUDNG_DEMODB> col authentication_type for a20
admin@MNYYI81SOQCUDNG_DEMODB> select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','NETWORK_PROTOCOL') authentication_type from dual;

AUTHENTICATION_TYPE
--------------------
tcps
```

Make sure you have connectivity (look into tnsnames.ora for host and port)

```
nc -vz adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com 1522
Connection to adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com port 1522 [tcp/ricardo-lm] succeeded!
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=59298716467964&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2474071.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=nvpxdkgyy_4

TNS_ADMIN was set as environment variable at SO level, I just removed. Is not the best solution, but it worked.